# Simple JOGL game running very slowly on a gtx 470

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I've been making a game for my computer science class.  For simplicity, I've just been making a set of minigames.  For fun, I tried to make a version of the classic Snake game in 3d.  The physics and collision detection works fine, and on the school computers (medium quality macs) the game runs very smoothly.  However, on my home computer, it runs at 8 fps.  My home computer runs on a gtx 470 with the latest drivers, and a query in the program confirms that the code is running on a gtx 470 with opengl 4.2.

Here's the render code (running in GLCanvas)

```
 GL2 gl = ( drawable.getGL()).getGL2();
     /*System.out.println(gl.glGetString(GL.GL_VENDOR)+"\n"+
                gl.glGetString(GL.GL_RENDERER)+"\n"+
                gl.glGetString(GL.GL_VERSION));*/

     gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //Init camera
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    // Perspective.
    float widthHeightRatio = (float) getWidth() / (float) getHeight();
    glu.gluPerspective(75, widthHeightRatio, 1, 2000);

    double dX, dY, dZ;
    if (player.locs.size()==0)
    {
        dX=0.1*player.vel.x;
        dY=0.1*player.vel.y;
        dZ=0.1*player.vel.z;
    }
    else
    {
        dX=player.xHead-player.locs.get(0).x;
        dY=player.yHead-player.locs.get(0).y;
        dZ=player.zHead-player.locs.get(0).z;

    }
    player.up.normalizeDist();
    double xPos=4*dX-0.1*player.up.x;
    double yPos=4*dY-0.1*player.up.y;
    double zPos=4*dZ-0.1*player.up.z;
    double desiredDist=0.2;
    double totalDist=Math.sqrt(xPos*xPos+yPos*yPos+zPos*zPos);
    xPos=xPos*desiredDist/totalDist;
    yPos=yPos*desiredDist/totalDist;
    zPos=zPos*desiredDist/totalDist;
    double camX=player.xHead-xPos;
    double camY=player.yHead-yPos;
    double camZ=player.zHead-zPos;
    glu.gluLookAt(xWidth*(camX), yWidth*(camY),zWidth*(camZ), xWidth*(player.xHead+2*dX), yWidth*(player.yHead+2*dY), zWidth*(player.zHead+2*dZ), player.up.x, player.up.y, -player.up.z);
    // Change back to model view matrix.
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();


    float SHINE_ALL_DIRECTIONS = 1;
    float[] lightPos = {xWidth/2, yWidth/2, zWidth/2, SHINE_ALL_DIRECTIONS};
    float[] lightColorAmbient = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f};
    float[] lightColorSpecular = {0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f};

    // Set light parameters.
    gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT1, GL2.GL_POSITION, lightPos, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT1, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, lightColorAmbient, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT1, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, lightColorSpecular, 0);

    // Enable lighting in GL.

    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT1);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHTING);


    // Set material properties.
    float[] rgba = {1f, 1f, 1f};
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL2.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, rgba, 0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL2.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, rgba, 0);
    gl.glMaterialf(GL2.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SHININESS, 0.5f);
    /*gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_BACK, GL.GL_AMBIENT, rgba, 0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_BACK, GL.GL_SPECULAR, rgba, 0);
    gl.glMaterialf(GL.GL_BACK, GL.GL_SHININESS, 0.5f);*/


   // gl.glColor3f(1f,1f,1f);
    if (camX>0)
    {

        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glNormal3d(1,0,0);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, zWidth);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, yWidth, zWidth);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, yWidth, 0);
        gl.glEnd();
    }
    if (camY>0)
    {
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glNormal3d(0, 1, 0);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, zWidth);
        gl.glVertex3d(xWidth, 0, zWidth);
        gl.glVertex3d(xWidth, 0, 0);
        gl.glEnd();
    }
    if (camZ>0)
    {
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glNormal3d(0, 0, 1);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
        gl.glVertex3d(xWidth, 0, 0);
        gl.glVertex3d(xWidth, yWidth, 0);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, yWidth, 0);
        gl.glEnd();
    }
    if (camX<1)
    {
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glNormal3d(-1, 0, 0);
        gl.glVertex3d(xWidth, 0, 0);
        gl.glVertex3d(xWidth, 0, zWidth);
        gl.glVertex3d(xWidth, yWidth, zWidth);
        gl.glVertex3d(xWidth, yWidth, 0);
        gl.glEnd();
    }
    if (camY<1)
    {
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glNormal3d(0, -1, 0);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, yWidth, 0);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, yWidth, zWidth);
        gl.glVertex3d(xWidth, yWidth, zWidth);
        gl.glVertex3d(xWidth, yWidth, 0);
        gl.glEnd();
    }
    if (camZ<1)
    {

        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glNormal3d(0, 0, 1);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, zWidth);
        gl.glVertex3d(xWidth, 0, zWidth);
        gl.glVertex3d(xWidth, yWidth, zWidth);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, yWidth, zWidth);
        gl.glEnd();
    }


    player.draw(xWidth, yWidth, zWidth, drawable, glu);
    for (int i=0; i<bullets.size(); i++)
    {
        bullets.get(i).draw(drawable, glu, xWidth, yWidth, zWidth);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<basicEntities.size(); i++)
    {
        basicEntities.get(i).draw( xWidth, yWidth, zWidth, drawable, glu);
    }
```

And then a lot of copy pasted calls to code like this: (xHead, yHead, and zHead are coordinates)

```
GL gl=drawable.getGL();
GL2 gl2=gl.getGL2();        
        gl2.glPushMatrix();
        gl2.glTranslated(xHead*xWidth, yHead*yWidth, zHead*zWidth);
        float[] rgba = {0.3f, 0.5f, 1f};
        gl2.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, rgba, 0);
        gl2.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, rgba, 0);
        gl2.glMaterialf(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SHININESS, 0.5f);
        GLUquadric head = glu.gluNewQuadric();
        glu.gluQuadricDrawStyle(head, GLU.GLU_FILL);
        glu.gluQuadricNormals(head, GLU.GLU_FLAT);
        glu.gluQuadricOrientation(head, GLU.GLU_OUTSIDE);
        final float radius = (float) (dotSize*xWidth);
        final int slices = 32;
        final int stacks = 32;
        glu.gluSphere(head, radius, slices, stacks);
        glu.gluDeleteQuadric(head);
        gl2.glPopMatrix();
```

Edit:  I can get the game to run faster by reducing the number of slices and stacks in the quadrics, but this makes the game rather ugly.
Also, I removed the a.add(this) (from the animator) and the game still runs.  Was I animating everything twice?  It's still slow though.

Comment: Modern GPU's (and their drivers) are not particularly optimized for immediate mode rendering. Also, your school computers may have integrated GPU's, so perhaps there's less latency for transfering data to the GPU (no PCI bus).

Answer (score 5):

I can't fully explain why it runs so much better on your school computer, but the way you are using OpenGL is an ancient way and is terrible for performance.

Using glBegin to draw will always be very expensive, because it must send every single vertex as a separate API call, which is bad for performance. You should instead look into rendering with Vertex Arrays (good) or Vertex Buffer Objects (better in most cases). Using these will require a slight shift in thinking, but I'm sure you can find many tutorials using those search terms.

I'm also not an expert on what glu does, though your use of gluSphere and gluQuadrics also makes me suspicious. Most of the work of the **glu** functions are probably not executed on the graphics card, so maybe every time you call gluSphere the CPU must recompute all the vertices of the sphere before it can do anything with the GPU. A much better solution would be to generate your own list of sphere vertices, upload it to GPU as a VBO, and then just execute the VBO draw call anytime you want to draw a sphere. That should save a huge amount of computation time.

Comment: At one point I looked at the implementation of FreeGLUT, and at least in that implementation gluSphere etc. were implemented by computing the vertices on the CPU, then drawing in immediate mode. So yeah, probably not the best choice for performance..